# Why is the currency symbol sometimes, but not always included in spacy MONEY entities?

Tags: spacy

In the sentence "I saved $6 hundred." spacy NER recognizes "$6 hundred" as MONEY entity.
So far, so good.

But in the sentence "I saved $600." it recognizes "600" as MONEY - without the dollar sign!
This seems inconsistent. Am I missing something?

Here's the code to reproduce:

```
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

def print_entities(txt):
    print("Entities for input: '{}'".format(txt))
    doc = nlp(txt)
    for entity in doc.ents:
        print('\t', entity.text, entity.label_)


print_entities("I saved $6 hundred.")
print_entities("I saved $600.")
```

This gives the output:

```
Entities for input: 'I saved $6 hundred.'
     $6 hundred MONEY
Entities for input: 'I saved $600.'
     600 MONEY
```

I'm doing this in a fresh python 3.6.8 virtual environment with spacy version 2.1.3 and en_core_web_sm version 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that the issue (1) is still here, (2) doesn't depend on the currency symbol, (3) only occurs when the entity is just a symbol + number (i.e., no literal expression), and (4) the symbols are not included in the span (you can list it, it doesn't appear) or the `entity.start_char` and `entity.end_char`.

A quick-and-dirty hack consists in testing whether the text starts AND ends up with a figure, in which case you get the currency symbol before or after. For example, if `source` is the initial document and `entity` the money entity:

```
def complete_text(source, entity):
    t=entity.text
    try:
        float( t[0] + t[len(t)-1] )
    except:
        return t
    if entity[0].nbor(-1).is_currency:
        return entity[0].nbor(-1).text + t
    else:
        return t + entity[0].nbor(1).text
```

Hope there will be some neater suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible work-around until a more satisfying solution is developed:

```
def money_merger(doc):
    with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
        for money in [e for e in doc.ents if e.label_ == 'MONEY']:
            if doc[money.start - 1].is_currency:
                retokenizer.merge(doc[
                money.start-1:money.end])
return doc

nlp.add_pipe(money_merger, after='ner')
```